Does .htaccess alone offer an authentication method that offers "remember me" and custom titles?
Basic authentication forgets the user once the browser is closed and browsers ignore its custom titles.
In my understanding Digest access authentication is not different in those aspects. So is there a way for .htaccess to define an alternate method that does support these two features?

When browsers decided to ignore the site-specified text for HTTP-integrated authentication, it wasn't that they specifically excluded Basic and Digest but not some other alternative – rather, they removed this capability for all mechanisms that relied on the browser's interface as the password prompt (mainly because people confuse it with the OS password dialogs; those used to look the same in IE6 back in the day). So if there was a third mechanism like this, it would just have received the exact same treatment – as long as it uses the browser's UI for the prompt.
So if you want .htaccess configuration, you'll need to find an Apache httpd module that implements HTML <form>-based dialogs, like the built-in mod_auth_form, which then uses cookies (session and long-term) for keeping the authentication state.

Problem is this module doesn't seem to be enabled by default...be it as it may, could you edit to add an .htaccess example with it for title + cookies? And are you sure the form can be built-in, e.g. AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "data:text/html,..."?
